# How to check mat-cell null or not in Angular

Tags: angular, mat-table

I am beginner for Angular and I am displaying my users list data in **mat-table** and my requirement is I want to check **mat-cell** empty or not if empty simply I would like to show "No value".

I wrote below code for my requirement but I am getting exceptions.

```html
<ng-container matColumnDef="email">
  <th mat-header-cell *matHeaderCellDef>Email</th>
  <td mat-cell *matCellDef="let element" *ngIf="element.email;else defaultValue">
    {{element.email}}
  </td>
  <ng-template #defaultValue>
    No value
  </ng-template>
</ng-container>
```

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You can't use two structural directives on one element so that consider the following solution:

```html
<td mat-cell *matCellDef="let element"> 
  <ng-container *ngIf="element.email; else defaultValue">
    {{element.email}}
  </ng-container>
</td>
<ng-template #defaultValue>
  No value
</ng-template>
```

Comment: Just to clarify, can the <ng-template> appear almost anywhere in the HTML template to allow reuse in multiple table cells?  Is there a best practice?

Answer (score 0):

*This works for me, I hope It Works for you!*

```
<ng-container matColumnDef="email">
  <th mat-header-cell *matHeaderCellDef>Email</th>
  <td mat-cell *matCellDef="let element">
    <ng-container *ngIf="element.email; else defaultValue">
      {{element.email}}
    </ng-container>
    <ng-template #defaultValue>
    </ng-template>
  </td>
</ng-container>
```

Comment: are you able to explain how that helps the issue?